# Dapp in Electron ? (without using Metamask)

Tags: electron, ethereum, web3js, metamask, decentralized-applications

I'm attempting to build a dApp (my first) for a university project.
One part of the project is a React based website, and the other is an Electron desktop app.

I'd like to be able to create, sign, and get data about "my contracts" without using Metamask, because Electron doesn't support chrome extensions.

Is there a library that will let me basically do what Metamask does but without the extension (And without sending the private key anywhere)?

I'll note that I have seen an article about how to use Metamask with Electron (Muon), but it seems to be very complex, and some of the tools listed in the article are tagged as deprecated anyways.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use MetaMask in Electron apps.

But you can use [WalletConnect](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82531/connecting-the-wallet-of-to-your-dapp-and-different-ethereum-wallet-types/82532#82532) that already may [have some desktop clients available](https://github.com/WalletConnect/walletconnect-monorepo/issues/450).

Answer (score 0):

You are able to load chrome extensions into ElectronJS now (https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/extensions/). I just tried setting it up but I'm not too familiar with the framework so really out of my depth. I was able to load the extension but the `ethereum` object wasn't injected and I'm not sure why.

I did however, find a repo and post about a project that was able to do it. I was not able to get it up and running though. Hope fully this will give you some idea of the work that needs that needs to be done.

Would love to hear about any progress if someone decides to take this on!

https://github.com/26rahulsingh/electron-metamask
https://medium.com/swapynetwork/integrating-metamask-with-electron-a-simple-secure-and-non-intrusive-approach-517a04da1656